# Gradle multi-module

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I've been learing Gradle lately. I'm already at stage of setting project with many modules.

My question is:

Is there any way for setting multi-modules project, some with spring-boot, some without it. Also I'm curiousit is possible to set different languages ​​for the module (Kotlin, Java)

Comment: Yes. And yes. Try doing it and come back if you have a concrete problem.

Comment: It's more like `good practice` problem. Should I place appling sprint-boot plugin to every modules that uses spring, same with Java/Kotlin? Or try using just root build.gradle?

Comment: The goal of the spring-boot plugin is to" package executable jar or war archives, run Spring Boot applications" (quoted from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/). So you should use it in the module that is supposed to create a spring boot application. If other modules just generate jar libraries, there is no reason to apply tot boot plugin.

Comment: Regarding Kotlin, "Kotlin sources can be mixed with Java sources in the same folder, or in different folders. The default convention is using different folders" (quoted from https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html). Just reading the few first sentences of the documentation answers your questions, doesn't it?